# Why does '5' + '9' give 110?

Tags: c

I am studying C. How is this answer 110?

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   void main()

    {
         char c1,c2,sum ;
         c1='5';
         c2='9';
         sum= c1+c2;
         printf("sum=%d",sum);

    }
```

Comment: There's no system where e.g. `'5' == 5`. With ASCII encoding the character `'5'` is equal to the integer `53`.

Comment: Them things there in the little `' '` (quotes) is ASCII characters, not numbers. You can see the ciphering used at the [ASCII Table](https://www.asciitable.com/) site. Lots of good fun to be had with 7-bit ASCII `:)` What if you were to write `printf("sum '%c' (%d) + '%c' (%d) = %d\n", c1, c1, c2, c2, sum);`  -- that might clear things up. (always include a `'\n'` character at the end of the last output so your program will be POSIX compliant)

Comment: OT: regarding: `void main()`   There are only two valid signatures for the 'main()` function.  they are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`  Notice they all have a return type of `int` not `void`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The character `'5'` has an ascii value of 53.
The character `'9'` has an ascii value of 57.

53 + 57 == 110.

Answer (score 1):

First things first:

1. The type `char` in C can be used in two ways, depending on how one uses it:

   **i.** It can store small integer values (up to 255 if treated as unsigned or [-128,127] if treated as signed) [1]. So one can use it to do arithmetic operations, provided they are careful with overflow.

   **ii.** (Integer) values stored as `char`s can be used to represent "characters" (i.e. alphanumeric symbols), which are used when displaying messages.
   **How does this representation work?**  The value of the char variable is looked upon the ASCII table, and the symbol that has the specific value is printed out.
   **Note**: This "functionality" is "optional": Char's are treated like integers throughout the code (case i.) and only when you invoke some function like `putchar()`, `printf("%c", ...)` this conversion happens and your code never actually "sees" it.

2. The single quotes in C are something similar to an operator: When you write a (*single*) character within single quotes, the compiler does the ASCII translation backwards; it takes that character, searches for it on the ASCII table, and returns the (integer) value that represents that character. So `'5'` essentially returns an integer value of `53` (and `'9'` has an ASCII value of `57`).

Using the above, then we observe that:

```c
char c1 = '5';
char c2 = '9';
```

is equivalent to

```c
char c1 = 53;
char c2 = 57;
```

only that in the first case, the compiler does the conversion for you so that you don't have to remember every value.

From then on, using the fact that `char` is an integer type,

```c
char sum = c1 + c2;
```

gives `sum` the value of 53+57=110.

One thing to note here: `sum`, being a `char` can also be used to print out a symbol using the ascii table. In fact, 110 corresponds to the symbol for `n`. So if the code had the line

```c
printf("%c\n", sum);
```

or

```c
putchar(sum);
```

The letter `n` would be printed on the screen.
This trick of adding/subtracting ASCII values to get to other values can be used in a few ways like converting lowercase to uppercase, converting numeric values to their actual integer values (e.g. from `'5'` to get `5`), and so on.

---

[1] A `char` variable uses 1 byte (i.e. 8 bits) to store its values. So it can store 2^8 = 256 values.

Comment: Not my downvote, but... "The single quotes in C are an operator" This is technically not correct, the single quotes create a character constant of type `int`.  "In fact, 110 corresponds to the symbol for o" Nope, `n`.

Comment: @Lundin True, 110 is `n`. A prime example of why single quotes are useful. Well even more technically ( :P ) , a set of characters in a language's lexicon that modify an expression/value are operators. But anyway, my point was that it is conceptually easier at the beginning to think of them as an operation that hides an integer value beneath. Anyway, changed it to "something like an operator"

Comment: From -128 to 127

Comment: A list of operators in the C language can be found in chapter 6.5 of ISO/IEC 9899:2018. Character constants are defined in 6.4.4.4. It isn't helpful to invent your own meaning to established, formal terms when teaching beginners.